# How to fetch a million records into Shiny R faster from postgresql?

Tags: r, postgresql, shiny, dplyr, data.table

I am trying to fetch a million records from postgres database. The shiny dashboard works fine when there is a small amount of data but as the data increases the time being taken to run the app increases. It now takes about 2 minutes to load the application.

```
config <- config::get()
pool <- dbPool(
drv = dbDriver("PostgreSQL"),
host = config$host,
dbname = config$dbname,
port = config$port,
user = config$user,
password = config$password
)

onStop(function() {
poolClose(pool)
})

get_data <- function(pool) {
appdata <- pool %>% tbl('matview')%>%collect()
return(appdata)
}
appdata <- get_data(pool = pool)
View(appdata)
```

The matview is the materialized view with 2 million rows(All the aggregations have been performed and data is reduced to minimum possible level). Processor Speed: 3.3GHz, Memory:16GB.
Is there any way the speed could be improved?

Thank you!!

Comment: Do you really need million rows in the app? Is it not possible to offload some logic to the DB? Databases are usually better suited for handling big datasets than shiny ...

Comment: @JindraLacko Yes I need all the data. Some parts of the dashboard requires all the data to be displayed.

Comment: Strange... And do all the 2M rows change? Consider keeping a local copy in the app and load only increments (changed records) from the DB.

Comment: @JindraLacko   I have a scatter plot displaying the turn around time for every user  over a period of 5 years(can select the date) and hover over on a point must display other related attributes to that user. No the rows will not change. Only new data will be added. I will you suggestion to keep a local copy. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Oki, this should be doable with an incremental load. Glad to be of service! :)